# R: Use lapply with a function acting on part of a split dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, split, lapply, numerical-integration

This R code is setting up an example of the issue I am attempting to resolve.  The data set measures a release of particles over non-uniform time intervals. The particle release is integrated over time using the trapezoid rule.

```
library(caTools)

test.data.frame <- data.frame( 
    sample = c('sample 1','sample 1','sample 1','sample 1',
               'sample 2','sample 2','sample 2','sample 2'))
test.data.frame$time <- c(1,2,4,6,1,4,5,6)
test.data.frame$material.released.g <- c(5,3,2,1,2,4,5,1)

split.test <- split(test.data.frame, test.data.frame$sample)

integrate.test <- function(x){
   dataframe.segment <- do.call(rbind.data.frame,x)
   return(trapz(dataframe.segment$time,dataframe.segment$material.released.g))
}
```

So far the integrate.test function appears to work on a single element of a list.

```
   > integrate.test(split.test[1])
   [1] 12

   > integrate.test(split.test[2])
   [1] 16.5
```

The lapply function gives zeros in the output.

```
  > lapply(split.test, integrate.test)
  $`sample 1`
  [1] 0

  $`sample 2`
  [1] 0
```

The output I am looking for is a data frame equivalent to:

```
expected.output <- data.frame(
    sample = c('sample 1','sample 2'), 
    total.material.released = c(12 , 16.5))
```

Is anyone able to help resolve the error code. Thanks!

Comment: This works: `lapply(split.test, function(x) integrate.test(list(x)))`, but you should understand the difference between `[` and `[[`. For instance, `integrate.test(split.test[[1]])` doesn't work (do you see why?). `lapply` subsets with `[[`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-and-notations-for-accessing-the-elements-of-a-lis  ... for those stumped like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the difference between `split.test[1]`, which is a one-element list containing a data frame, and `split.test[[1]]`, which is the data frame stored in list element [[1]].

Your function, by calling `do.call(rbind.data.frame, x)`, is expecting that `x` will be a list. But `lapply(split.test, integrate.test)` actually feeds it a data frame. Here's what happens when you feed `integrate.test` a data frame rather than a (generic) list:

```
x = do.call(rbind.data.frame, split.test[[1]])
x
```

> ```
>                     c.1..1..5. c.1..2..3. c.1..4..2. c.1..6..1.
> sample                       1          1          1          1
> time                         1          2          4          6
> material.released.g          5          3          2          1
> ```

`do.call` operates over a list. If you feed it a generic list (like `split.test[1]`, which is a one-element list) it tries to `rbind` each list element. If the list contained several data frames, it would stack them into a single data frame. But there's only one element--the data frame contained in element 1 of `split.test`--so that's what gets returned.

However, when you run `do.call(rbind, split.test[[1]])` you're giving `do.call` a data frame to operate on. A data frame is a special kind of list in which each column is a list element. So `do.call` takes the columns of your original data frame, transposes them into rows and stacks them. The integration returns 0, because the columns it wants to operate on no longer exist. When you reference those non-existent columns, values of `NULL` are returned instead of the data you were expecting and `trapz(NULL, NULL)` is zero.

The function will work if you use the data frame directly and skip the `do.call` step:

```
integrate.test <- function(x){
  #dataframe.segment <- do.call(rbind.data.frame,x)
  dataframe.segment = x
  return(trapz(dataframe.segment$time,dataframe.segment$material.released.g))
}

lapply(split.test, integrate.test)
```

> ```
> $`sample 1`
> [1] 12
>
> $`sample 2`
> [1] 16.5
> ```

Of course this can be shortened to:

```
integrate.test <- function(x){
  return(trapz(x$time,x$material.released.g))
}
```

Or you can just use `trapz` directly, without wrapping it in a function.

Comment: For completeness: e.o <- data.frame(sample = levels(test.data.frame$sample), total.material.released.g = unlist(lapply(split.test, function(x) trapz(x$time,x$material))))